# R - find cases in list of lists which meet specific condition

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a large list of lists with three columns (TRUE/FALSE) per case. I want to find out for which cases all three columns = TRUE.

Example data:

```
l1 <- list( c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE") , c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE") , c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE") )
l2 <- list( c("TRUE","TRUE","TRUE") , c("TRUE","TRUE","TRUE") , c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE") )
l3 <- list( c("TRUE","TRUE","TRUE") , c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE") , c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE") ) 
mylist <- list(l1,l2,l3)
```

In the output I need to see which cases in which lists meet the condition, so something like
l2[[1]]
l3[[1]]

Hope that someone can help! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `rapply`:

```r
rapply(mylist, \(x) all(x == "TRUE"), how = "list")
```

output

```r
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[1]][[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[1]][[3]]
[1] FALSE


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]][[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]][[3]]
[1] FALSE


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]][[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]][[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

Or, if you want a more compact result:

```r
rapply(mylist, \(x) all(x == "TRUE"), how = "list") |>
  lapply(\(x) which(unlist(x)))

[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

Another compact solution with `rrapply::rrapply`:

```r
rrapply::rrapply(mylist, \(x) all(x == "TRUE"), how = "melt")

  L1 L2            value
1  2  1 TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
2  2  2 TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
3  3  1 TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
```

---

Note: you probably have logical vector in your real data, which is made of `c(TRUE, FALSE)` (without the brackets). In that case, `all(x)`, is sufficient.

Comment: Nice use of `base::rapply()`. Incidentally, R will coerce "TRUE" to TRUE and "FALSE" to FALSE (try putting them in an `if()` statement), so you could just do `rapply(mylist, all, how = "list")`. But it's probably to do it your way rather than rely on arcane coercion rules...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this helps

```
 which(sapply(mylist, \(x) sapply(x, \(y) all(y == 'TRUE'))), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

or use

```
lapply(mylist, \(x) Filter(\(y) all(y == 'TRUE'), x))
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE"
```

---

Or may be

```
> lapply(mylist, \(x) lapply(x, \(y) all(y == 'TRUE')))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[1]][[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[1]][[3]]
[1] FALSE


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]][[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]][[3]]
[1] FALSE


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]][[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]][[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another trick using `lapply`

```
lapply(
  mylist,
  function(x) {
    as.list(
      colMeans(type.convert(list2DF(x), as.is = TRUE)) == 1
    )
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[1]][[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[1]][[3]]
[1] FALSE


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]][[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]][[3]]
[1] FALSE


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]][[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]][[3]]
[1] FALSE
```